# Equilvalence among two Scheduling problems

Tags: ds.algorithms, ds.data-structures, scheduling, equivalence

I have two problems for scheduling:

1. Packets arrive at a router. Router schedules them i.e. router determines which one will go out first and which one last. Here, the problem is which packet to send first and which to last.
2. Packets arrive to a scheduler and it decides which packet will go out on which path. Here, the problem is to choose between paths -- which we call scheduling.

Is there any equivalence between the two problems ?

What do I mean by equivalence : Like consider a FIFO scheduling policy in 1. Is there any policy for problem 2 that can be fundamentally called similar to FIFO policy in 1 ?

Is there any transformation from a solution of problem 1 to 2 ?

Comment: Are you interested in a sequencing problem, or do the packets carry durations that make this a scheduling problem?

Comment: @AndrásSalamon No packets don't carry durations.